# How can I determine the file name that is being executed in a mono C# environment when the file was created with mkbundle2?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, mono

When running a C# application under mono with the "mono " command, the following works:

```
var fileName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```

But after packaging the assemblies into a single file using mono's mkbundle2, the line above does not return the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, this works:

```
var fileName = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
```

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName under Mono returns path to the Mono ("/usr/bin/mono")